# How to add decimal and remove text from alphanumerical string

Tags: vba, excel

I have a huge amount of data which is alphanumerical and I need to convert it to purely numerical. Which no text in the string.

Ex.
C0424.100 ---> 424.100 (or 0424.100)

There always is 3 places after the decimal. Any tips on how to go about this? I'm pretty new to VBA. So basically I need to remove all text and a decimal with three digits to the right of it.

Comment: Is there always only 1 letter before the number? ("C" in your example).  If not, what is the range of possible formats?

Answer (score 0):

This is well described in [String functions and how to use them](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/String-functions-and-how-to-use-them-965efa84-7009-4603-9765-2eb4a099ec72?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)

However, this should get you started.  I would handle the formatting in Excel afterwards, but this is the simple string to number conversion.  If the strings are more complex, consider using the Search string function to find the numbers, then use Right, Left, Mid functions to trim the string.  Lastly use the CDbl() function to convert the string to the double.

Macro code as follows:

```
Sub temp()
'
' temp Macro

    Range("A2").Select
        stringToConvert = Selection.Value
        trimmedString = Right(stringToConvert, Len(stringToConvert) - 1)
        numberToDisplay = CDbl(trimmedString)
    Range("A3").Value = numberToDisplay
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you even need VBA? If your data always has just one leading alpha character then you can just use standard Excel functions. For an entry in A2 that you want to convert, place the following formula in a convenient cell (e.g. B2):

```
=VALUE(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for VBA.  Something like:

```
=--MID(A1,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789")),99)
```

will return the string starting with the first digit, and convert it to a numeric value.  You can then format it in the cell however you wish.

The above will work with any number of non-digit leading characters.  If will only have a single non-digit character, then @Skippy answer is simpler

If you have to have a VBA routine, something like the following should work -- it will extract the first numeric substring in the string.  It does not matter if there are non-digits before or after.  And, if there are no digits, the function will return the `#NUM!` error

---

```
Option Explicit
Function ExtractNums(S As String) As Variant
    Dim I As Long

For I = 1 To Len(S)
    If IsNumeric(Mid(S, I, 1)) Then
        ExtractNums = Val(Mid(S, I))
        Exit Function
    End If
Next I

ExtractNums = CVErr(xlErrNum)

End Function
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I got UDF options for you.

***`Option 1`***: If you want to remove all the alphas from the beginning of string:

```
Function RemoveFirstAlphas(txt As String) As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(txt)
        Select Case Mid$(txt, i, 1)
            Case "0" To "9": Exit For
            Case Else: Mid$(txt, i, 1) = Chr(32)
        End Select
    Next
    RemoveFirstAlphas = Trim(txt)
End Function
```

***`Option 2`***: If you want to remove all the alphas from entire string:

```
Function RemoveAllAlphas(txt As String) As String
    Dim ObjRegex As Object
    Set ObjRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With ObjRegex
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "[a-zA-Z\s]+"
        RemoveAllAlphas = .Replace(Replace(txt, "-", Chr(32)), vbNullString)
    End With
End Function
```